# Jquery Ajax loading Problem

Tags: jquery

I have a function to load a html part into a element in main index page kinda like this

```
$(".ajax").click(function() {
         //load a page into a element
});
```

This works
But the HTML part which i have just loaded also have links that need to trigger same function above, but it does not.

Until I save that function in a separate .js file and load in the main index file as well as all other files from where I need to trigger that function even though these internal files are going to loaded into the the first main file .

Is there any way for a function in the index file to run from the html document that is loaded inside a element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear, but if you want elements with the `ajax` class inside the loaded content to trigger the event, you can use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), like this:

```
$(".ajax").live("click", function() {
         //load a page into a element
});
```

Comment: Bull eyes dude, that fixed everything. One more question can we use that .live in

$(document).ready();

Comment: Yes, you can use it at any point, and from that point on anything that matches the selector no matter when it is loaded will trigger the event.

Comment: But this is not executing

$(document).live("ready", function() {
 $(".accordion").accordion({ alwaysOpen: false, autoheight: false, clearStyle: true, active: true   });
});

Comment: A `document.ready` can only occur once per page - loading content into an element doesn't trigger it. Why would you want to live-bind a once-occurring event?

Comment: I have used accordions on many places, and all of them are loaded through .load() function so, i need to write same line of code in every html file that is loaded.  

Like before do you know how to initiate a plugin for all matching selectors that are present or will be loaded afterwards

Like to initiate accordion in classes with "accordion" i use

$(document).ready(function() {

$(".accordion").accordion({ alwaysOpen: false, autoheight: false, clearStyle: true, active: true   });


});

Comment: In that case you should probably stuff that into a function, then call it in your AJAX handler or pass it as a callback to the `load()` method. You could also use the global AJAX functions: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events#Global_Events